# Scheduler in Android to a specific date

Tags: android, timer, scheduler, countdown

I'm trying to make a scheduler that will give you a notification when the scheduled date and time comes. I'm using a broadcast receiver class and I've made it to work for day.

It means you can select any day and time within a month it will work just fine but I'm having a lot of problems if the user selects next month or year
Here is my code on schedule button click.

Here mDay, mMonth , mYear, mHour, mMinute are the selected date and time by the user for his activity and cday,cmonth,cyear are the current date and time.

```
btn_schedule.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("Entered in Alarm on click");

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            Minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            cday = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);
            cmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            cyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            dday = mDay - cday;
            dmonth = mMonth - cmonth;
            dyear = mYear - cyear;

            if (dyear == 0) {
                if (dmonth == 0) {
                    if (dday == 0) {
                        long CurrentMilli = (mHour * 3600 * 1000) + (mMinute * 60 * 1000);
        long SelectedMilli = (Hour * 3600 * 1000) + (Minute * 60 * 1000);

        long diff = CurrentMilli - SelectedMilli;
        diff1 = diff;
        System.out.println("difference and " + diff + "diff1" + diff1);

        new CountDownTimer(diff, 1000) { // adjust the
            // milli
            // seconds
            // here

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();
    }

                    } else {// Else if day is not the same
                        int dh = 24 - Hour; // today's remaining hours till
                                            // next date
                        int dm = 60 - Minute;// today's remaining minutes
                                                // till next date
                        long dhm = dh * 3600000;// in milli
                        long dmm = dm * 60000;// in milli
                        long totaltm = dhm + dmm;
                        diff1 = totaltm;
                        long lh = mHour * 3600000;// selected hours in milli
                        long lm = mMinute * 60000;// selected min in milli
                        ltt = lh + lm;

                        new CountDownTimer(totaltm, 1000) { // adjust the
                            // milli
                            // seconds
                            // here

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
                                dday--;
                                forDay1(dday);
                            }
                        }.start();

                    }
                } else {
                    // Else if month is not the same



                }

            } else {// Else if year is not the same

            }
            long a = diff1;
            Long alertTime = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() + a;
            Intent alertIntent = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, Alerts.class);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alertTime, PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(HomeScreen.this, 2, alertIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            System.out.println("Notification is called");
            Intent moreinfo = new Intent(HomeScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
            TaskStackBuilder tsb = TaskStackBuilder
                    .create(getApplicationContext());
            tsb.addParentStack(HomeScreen.class);
            tsb.addNextIntent(moreinfo);



        }
    });
```

Here is my Broadcast class:

```
public class Alerts extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside Service");
        createNotification(context, "Times Up!", "Start Your Activity!",
                "Click here to enter the application!");

    }

    public void createNotification(Context context, String msg, String msgtext,
            String msgalert) {
        System.out.println("Method inside service is called");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(
                context, HomeScreen.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder ncb = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(msg).setContentText(msgtext)
                .setTicker(msgalert).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

        ncb.setContentIntent(pi);
        ncb.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(2, ncb.build());

    }

}
```

And this code is working for any day within a month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do all that custom logic of calculating the differences `ddat` and the big `if (dyear == 0) {`... Just set the user-selected fields to the `Calendar`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(mYear, mMonth, mDay, mHour, mMinute);
```

And then you can use the new Calendar's timestamp as your alert time.

```
long alertTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
```